# Phonegap: How to change the childbrowser window size on Android?

Tags: cordova, android-webview

I have implemented `phonegap childbrowser plugin`on `Android` and i am calling it from another webview but it is getting displayed on the whole screen and i dont want it to take full screen.

So is there any way to adjust the childbrowser window size so that caller webview look behind the new child window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in childBrowser.java, you can find the following lines:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
```

Change the width and height as you need. Also you can add new parameters to set it by javascript.

HTH.